# In Rice Boy, what were the fulfiller's three changes of form?

Tags: webcomics, prophecy, rice-boy

On [page 275](http://www.rice-boy.com/see/index.php?c=275) of *Rice Boy*, Parod states that "The fulfiller will be thrice transfigured— and in each new form his own nature will be clearer to him."

At the climax, on [page 414](http://www.rice-boy.com/see/index.php?c=414), it is stated that a certain character has satisfied this requirement.  However, I wasn't clear as to what these three changes of form were.  A few panels later the character is shown in flashbacks with three different appearances, but this would only be two changes of form.  Can anyone explain this?

(Please excuse the oblique wording, as I want to avoid giving away the ending for those who might not have read the comic.)

Comment: With the use of spoilertags (put >! before a paragraph), you could edit in the information that gives away the ending in such a way that anyone who doesn't want to know won't see it.